# How to set an a second Auto increment column per user?

Tags: java, mysql, triggers, auto-increment, invoice

I know this question has been asked before and most of the answers warn about doing so or suggest a solution for MyISAM but I'm using InnoDB.
I'm trying to generate an Invoice or Bill for the user for him to give out to me (Business plan requirement) !

**The thing is that in my country the reference of the ID of the bill for the same person should be ordered or he will be audited for the missing bills. Like for example he gave me one bill with 0001 and the second one is 0005. He will be interrogated for the missing 4.**

So I need to have a custom auto-increment per UserID.

User 1 - idUser= 1 ,idBill = 1

User 1 - idUser= 1 ,idBill = 2

User 2 - idUsr = 2 , idBill = 1

Some threads suggested using triggers while others warned about table locks. I personally not familiar with triggers so I steer away from them since they require maintenance.

I am using Java and MySQL.

Comment: *Some threads suggested using triggers while others warned about table locks.* To avoid table locks use additional MyISAM base table for autoincrement generation.

Comment: I'm not a DB expert but if your system doesn't remove or duplicate invoices you could generate the id as the number of existing invoices + 1, e.g. `.... id = (select count(*) from invoice where user =...) + ! ...`. You might also try to store the invoice count in a column (e.g. user table or something better designed), read it from there and increment in a separate query.

Comment: @Thomas This may produce duplicate values in concurrent threads.

Comment: @Akina you're right, that would have to be handled.

Comment: How did you manage to provide an example comprising just 3 rows, and still get it wrong?

Comment: Anyway, don't do this. Just calculate the sequences 'on-the-fly', if necessary.

Comment: Oops, I stayed up until 7 am so my brain must have been slow.  @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE main (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>                    primary_id CHAR(3), 
>                    secondary_id INT) ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE auxiliary (primary_id CHAR(3), 
>                         secondary_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
>                         PRIMARY KEY (primary_id, secondary_id)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER generate_secondary_id
> BEFORE INSERT 
> ON main
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     INSERT INTO auxiliary (primary_id) VALUES (NEW.primary_id);
>     SET NEW.secondary_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO main (primary_id) VALUES
> ('A01'),
> ('A01'),
> ('B01'),
> ('C01'),
> ('A01'),
> ('B01'),
> ('A01'),
> ('B01');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM main;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | primary_id | secondary_id
> -: | :--------- | -----------:
>  1 | A01        |            1
>  2 | A01        |            2
>  3 | B01        |            1
>  4 | C01        |            1
>  5 | A01        |            3
>  6 | B01        |            2
>  7 | A01        |            4
>  8 | B01        |            3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c61979a50a63a00cca2dae4990adf06)*

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you a lot, my savior! 
is there any disadvantage to this solution I should be aware of ?

Comment: @ZiedOrabi Except the presence of additional table which data does not allow deletion? Maybe, some disadvantage exists, but I don't know about it.

Comment: Thanks again. I will post something if I ever encountered a problem